# comparing 2 string in a do while cycle

Tags: c++

So my problem is this i made this function and on the cycle do i want it to repeat until the user insert the letter "n" so i did a strcmp but its not working, there isnt any errors it compiles but it doesnt do what is suppose, please help me.

```
void insereTabuleiro(TABULEIRO **tini, TABULEIRO **tfim){
TABULEIRO *novo = (TABULEIRO*) malloc(sizeof(TABULEIRO));
int  a=0;
char str1[] = "n";
char str2[] = "";

if(novo==NULL){
    system("cls");
    printf("Erro na reserva de memoria.\n");
    system("pause");
    return;
}
 system("cls");
 do{

printf("Insira a posiçao das cartas.\n->");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%d",&novo->t.n_casa);
printf("Pretende inserir mais casas?\n Para continuar prima y, caso n queira introduzir mais casas prima n->");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%c",&str2);

}while(strcmp(str1, str2) == 0);


if(*tini==NULL){
    novo->t.id=1;
}
else{
    novo->t.id = (*tfim)->t.id + 1;
}
//inserirListaP(novo->s, &(*inicio), &(*fim));
printf("ID da casa - %d\n",novo->t.id);
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: you're reading char, but compare it as string, replace `char str2[] = "";` with `char str2;` and `while(strcmp(str1, str2) == 0);` with `while(str2 != 'n');`

Comment: i did but it doesnt work i dont know why